# how to set the z-order for diagram object in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

How to set the property Z-order for the diagram object in enterprise architect through addin.Because when the diagram objects is added to diagram we have one parent diagram object A and we want one more diagram object B to be placed on diagram object A.But diagram object B is going behind A and not placing on top of Diagram object A.So using Z-order in addin it was achieved.So how can this property can be set in Addin while adding diagram object to diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diagramObject.sequence` to set the z-order. See [documentation](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/diagramobjects.html).